# What does screen:0:0 mean? Windows OS

Tags: javascript, webapi, getusermedia

Context :
I was working with WebAPI MediaDevices.getUserMedia(), and trying to capture the user device video.

The media stream outputs to this interface. Below is the console log for the Entire screen share.

```
0: MediaStreamTrack
contentHint: ""
enabled: true
id: "e6438e84-8139-4755-add6-ef32cc5e0aa6"
kind: "video"
label: "screen:0:0"
muted: false
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
```

What does this "label: screen:0:0" means? How Can I identify which monitor/screen this belongs to?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:{} , audio: true})
.then(stream => {
    // inject stream object as a source for video element //
    console.log(stream.id)

    document.getElementById('vid').srcObject = stream
    document.getElementById('vid').play

    console.log(stream.getTracks())

    // inject stream object as a source for video element //
})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

FYI-

- I have two monitors. the level for them is not in sequence. My primary monitor levels as "screen:0:0" and secondary as "screen:3:0".
- When I shared a single application/window, it was labeled as "window:1247096:0". When I did a little research I found that the integer "1247096" is a window handler(HWND).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why do you need to know which monitor has been selected?

Comment: A screen doesn't have to be linked to a monitor. You can create multiple screens and access them through different protocols like VNC or SSH. A screen is one output of your window system. You can configure as many screens as you want in your window system. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Key_terms) you can find the definitions for X Window System.

Comment: Once I am able to map this label. I have a python script running which will capture this label and mouse events.  use PyAuroGUI library to perform the action.

Comment: If you're asking how to find the display or monitor linked to a specific screen, it depends on your window system.

Comment: @jabaa I am focusing on windows OS.

Comment: I don't know, how the Windows window systems work. But you should consider that it may not be possible to find this out in the browser. You could probably find this out in Python or in JavaScript on Node.js if Windows provides an API for this.

Comment: @jabaa, I tried to get the display/monitor name using Python and also .net  library. both of them gave the same output as "//./Display4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239573/discussion-between-deepak-dash-and-jabaa).

Comment: As I already said, I have no experience with Windows, its window systems (I don't even know if Windows has a separate window system) or .NET. I can't help here.